# Android fragment factory method vs constructor overloading

Tags: android, android-fragments

First of all, I already know that the FragmentManager often destroys then re-creates the Fragment using the default constructor. The coders must save important things in a Bundle of arguments once in the factory method, then take them out every time the Fragment is re-created in **onCreate(Bundle)**.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String MY_STRING_CONSTANT = "param";
    private int mIntegerMember;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mIntegerMember= getArguments().getInt(MY_STRING_CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

My question is, is there any difference between this:

```
// Inside MyFragment.java
public MyFragment() {
    // No-argument constructor required by the FragmentManager.
}
public static MyFragment newInstance(int param) {
    // Factory method
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(MY_STRING_CONSTANT, param);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

// Somewhere else
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, MyFragment.newInstance(123)).commit();
```

And this:

```
// Inside MyFragment.java
public MyFragment() {
    // No-argument constructor required by the FragmentManager.
}
public MyFragment(int param) {
    // Parameterized constructor
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(MY_STRING_CONSTANT, param);
    setArguments(args);
}

// Somewhere else
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, new MyFragment(123)).commit();
```

I can see nothing which prevents the FragmentManager from calling the no-argument constructor. And the data I save in the parameterized constructor (in a Bundle object) will be preserved and restore during **onCreate()**, just like when I use the factory method.

Comment: Great question, I've been wondering this myself. The only thing I can think of is inheritance. It'd be better to use an overloaded constructor than the static newInstance method.

Comment: I never saw a single factory function in C++ and C#. So I don't want to use this ugly thing in Java either, unless there is a compelling reason.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is maybe Google thinks we may initialize member variables in the parameterized constructor, which will never be re-initialized when they call the no-argument constructor. By suggesting us to use the static factory method, they force us to bind everything to the Bundle and then, both we and they take these arguments out of the Bundle in **onCreate(Bundle)**, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: I think you are correct. That is the only value I see in it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Android never directly invokes a non-default constructor (nor a factory method) - technically, it doesn't really matter which you use. You can call `setArguments` (in an arbitrary method, even in a constructor) any time before you add the Fragment and that bundle will be saved/restored for you if the Fragment is recreated. Views also have special constructors invoked by Android, but you can make your own with arbitrary arguments if you wish (they just won't get invoked by Android).

Code for `Fragment.setArguments`:

```
/**
 * Supply the construction arguments for this fragment.  This can only
 * be called before the fragment has been attached to its activity; that
 * is, you should call it immediately after constructing the fragment.  The
 * arguments supplied here will be retained across fragment destroy and
 * creation.
 */
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    if (mIndex >= 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already active");
    }
    mArguments = args;
}
```

Code for `Fragment.instantiate`:

```
    /**
     * Create a new instance of a Fragment with the given class name.  This is
     * the same as calling its empty constructor.
     *
     * @param context The calling context being used to instantiate the fragment.
     * This is currently just used to get its ClassLoader.
     * @param fname The class name of the fragment to instantiate.
     * @param args Bundle of arguments to supply to the fragment, which it
     * can retrieve with {@link #getArguments()}.  May be null.
     * @return Returns a new fragment instance.
     * @throws InstantiationException If there is a failure in instantiating
     * the given fragment class.  This is a runtime exception; it is not
     * normally expected to happen.
     */
    public static Fragment instantiate(Context context, String fname, Bundle args) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = sClassMap.get(fname);
            if (clazz == null) {
                // Class not found in the cache, see if it's real, and try to add it
                clazz = context.getClassLoader().loadClass(fname);
                sClassMap.put(fname, clazz);
            }
            Fragment f = (Fragment)clazz.newInstance();
            if (args != null) {
                args.setClassLoader(f.getClass().getClassLoader());
                f.mArguments = args;
            }
            return f;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                    + ": make sure class name exists, is public, and has an"
                    + " empty constructor that is public", e);
        } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                    + ": make sure class name exists, is public, and has an"
                    + " empty constructor that is public", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                    + ": make sure class name exists, is public, and has an"
                    + " empty constructor that is public", e);
        }
    }
```

`Fragment.instantiate` is called when Android wants to create an instance of your Fragment. It simple calls through to `Class.newInstance`, which is a Java method to create a class using the default, zero-arg constructor. Looking at this code, there seems to be no problem with creating additional constructor and in calling `setArguments` within it.

As an a convention, it is typical to use a factory method when working with Fragments. Most [official sample Fragment code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) also uses factory methods. Here are some possible reasons why:

1. If you are writing a custom constructor (with arguments), you will have to specify a zero-arg constructor as well. A common mistake is to create a custom constructor but forget to define a zero-arg constructor - this will lead to a crash when Android tries to invoke the zero-arg constructor when recreating your Fragment.
2. When creating a custom constructor, you may be tempted to directly assign the constructor arguments to fields. This is how pretty much any other Java class is written (and therefore how you will naturally want to write classes). Since Android will only invoke the zero-arg constructor on a Fragment, this data will not be available to any recreated instances. As you already know, using `setArguments` is the way to solve this. Even though you can do this within a constructor, using a factory method makes it more obvious that this class cannot be constructed in a normal way, reducing the possibility of committing the above mistake (or similar).

Comment: An unrelated question though. If my Fragment is simple and has nothing which need to be saved during destruction/creation, should I provide a factory method which simply returns a new instance, or just use the default constructor directly?

Comment: If you think you may need to pass arguments in the future, creating a factory method would make the transition easier. A lot of the time I am too lazy to do that and I just use the default constructor directly.

Comment: sClassMap has private access. circa 2018

Answer (score 4):

The `FragmentManager` implementation calls the default constructor of the `Fragment`. I would think that it would involve a lot of overhead to be able to determine which arguments to pass to a non-default constructor, so the Android team decided to go the `Bundle` route. If you do use a non-default constructor the data you pass to it, will not be kept during recreation, hence you will end up with `null` pointers. By using the `setArguments()`/`getArguments()` mechanism you guarantee that `FragmentManager` will initialize the `Fragment` correctly.

When you do this call:

```
transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, new MyFragment(123));
```

it will be guaranteed that the first time will be fine. Now, lets say that the user rotates the screen (`setRetainInstance()` is not set), the `FragmentManager` will create a new instance of the `Fragment` by calling:

```
new MyFragment(); //the default constructor.
```

This means that all the variables that were supposed to be initialized in the non-default constructor will be `null`.

The docs tell us to avoid overloading `Fragment`'s constructor, I would stick to their rules. You might get some unexpected behavior if you try to overload the constructor (even if you do `setArguments()` in the overloaded constructor).

Comment: You would definitely have to save the information yourself with an overloaded constructor, where-as using the bundle arguments you can guarantee the Android framework will pass the same ones in when it recreates the Fragment without you having to save and restore state

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If he does use a non-default constructor, like he does on the second case, the `FragmentManager` will still call the default constructor if he needs to recreate the `Fragment`, hence variables will not be initialized properly.

Comment: The data I pass to the non-default constructor was saved in a Bundle then attach to the _Fragment_ using **setArguments(Bundle)**. The argument Bundle will be saved during the destruction and re-creation of the Fragment.

Comment: I still think it might not work. `setArguments()` is called on the non-default constructor which the `FragmentManager` will not call upon recreation.

Comment: The non-default constructor is never meant to be called by the FragmentManager, just like the factory method. It is only used by the programmers.

Comment: You cannot even run your code if you overload a fragment constructor: `Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead`

Comment: Don't let that warning fool you. It does build, and does run without any problem (so far).

Comment: You can try and see what happens. I, personally, would stick with the suggested pattern.

Comment: I am currently using the factory method pattern, too, to avoid potential unwanted issues, until I know mine is safe to use. The only reason I can think of is maybe Google thinks we may initialize member variables in non-default constructor, which will never be re-initialized when they call the default constructor. By suggesting us to use the static factory method, they force us to bind everything to the **Bundle** and take them out in **onCreate(Bundle)**.

Comment: Right. The factory method is the preferred pattern. Your method might work, but it is not adviced.